# AVG/COUNT MySQL query NOT working

Tags: mysql

I am not very experienced in MySQL queries so I might be doing something wrong.
Simplified my query is like this:

```
SELECT item.*, AVG(itemRating.rating) as 'rating', COUNT(itemRating.rating) as 'ratingCount' 
  FROM item, itemRating 
 WHERE item.id IN (...) 
   AND itemRating.item_fk = item.id 
 GROUP BY itemRating.item_fk
```

It works fine, except for when an item has no rating (no record in the itemRating table). Is there any way I can solve this without losing information?

Comment: How can it work, if you group wrong columns?

Comment: How do you mean 'wrong columns'?

Comment: You write: `SELECT item.*, AVG(itemRating.rating) as 'rating' ...  GROUP BY itemRating.item_fk` It seems to me that you need to write either `SELECT itemRating.item_fk, AVG(itemRating.rating) as 'rating' ...  GROUP BY itemRating.item_fk` or `SELECT item.*, AVG(itemRating.rating) as 'rating' ...  GROUP BY item.*` (You can't write `GROUP BY item.*` I did that because I don't know what columns you have in the `item` table, you need to specify every column of the `item` in the `GROUP BY` clause)

Comment: It seems better to write GROUP BY item.id than GROUP BY itemRating.item_fk, you are right. itemRating.item_fk is a fk=foreign key linking to item.id, so the query will give no problems.

Comment: You didn't even understand what I meant, I guess you need to read more about group by and how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT item.id, 
       AVG(itemRating.rating) as 'rating', 
       COUNT(itemRating.rating) as 'ratingCount' 
  FROM item
  LEFT JOIN itemRating ON itemRating.item_fk = item.id 
 WHERE item.id IN (...) 
 GROUP BY item.id
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I think I should update my MySQL-basics :)